# Move Multiple images in iOS

Tags: swift, imageview, touch

I have multiple images in a view controller. I am trying to implement the touch method to drag the images.  When I try to drag a single image view all the image views are dragging. Here is the code I am using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var img1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var img2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var img3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var img4: UIImageView!

var location = CGPoint(x: 0 , y:0)

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first{
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        if touch.view == img1 {
            print("img1 tapped")
            img1.center = location
        }
        else if touch.view == img2 {
            print("img2 tapped")
            img2.center = location
        }
        else if touch.view == img3 {
            print("img3 tapped")
            img3.center = location
        }
    }

    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first{
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        if touch.view == img1 {
            print("img1 tapped")
            img1.center = location
        }
        else if touch.view == img2 {
            print("img2 tapped")
            img2.center = location
        }
        else if touch.view == img3 {
            print("img3 tapped")
            img3.center = location
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is fine and should work. Check if your image views have multiple outlets.

Comment: yes.. have an outlet for each image view..

Comment: and i have not added  super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event) in the touchMoved method..

Comment: can't figure out how to get this done... any help.???

Comment: tried every alternate code.. but sometimes all the images start moving else images are not clicked..

Comment: Tested your code and it works fine. You might have a problem some where else in your codes. if you want you can put your project on github so I can help you further.

Comment: Why is it not working for me.??

Comment: I'm afraid i can't help you without more information. As I said I can take a look at your project if you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to take array of UIimageView and then set recognizer. So each and every recognizer wil be set in NSUser Default.

Comment: can't this be achieved by using the code mentioned above.??

Comment: No. you have to take one colletionview horizontal and on didSelect Action or on any action addsubview to View. Then you need to append that imageViewview into array of imageView. This will be the logic.